# rsvp button (users can only rsvp once)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So currently users can rsvp multiple times for the same event. That is obviously problematic for my website so I want it that a single user can only rsvp once for a specific post/event. After they have made their Rsvp I want the rsvp button to disappear. Heres is how my code is looking.

## show.html.erb

```
id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @post.date %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>User_id:</strong>
  <%= @post.user_id %>
</p>
<p><strong>Address:</strong> <%= @post.address %></p>
<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @post.description %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>registered:</strong>
    <%=@post.users.length%>
</p>






<% if current_user == @post.user %>
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%end%>
 <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

<div class="rsvp"><%= button_to "Rsvp now", rsvps_post_path(@post), class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>





<div class="map"><%= image_tag "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{@post.latitude},#{@post.longitude}&markers=#{@post.latitude},#{@post.longitude}&zoom=12&size=450x400&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCKzKMEhSNgwSXf7WV71pHWgzdpMkPn8W4",
class: 'img-fluid img-rounded', alt: "#{@post} on the map"%>
</div>
```

## post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
 geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
after_validation :reverse_geocode


  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :users, through: :rsvps

  validates :name, presence: true
```

## user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         has_many :posts

          has_many :rsvps
          has_many :posts, through: :rsvps

          validates :email, presence: true
```

## rsvp.rb

```
class Rsvp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

#rsvp migration

```
class Rsvp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

So I've looked around in Stackoverflow and googled for a bit but I'm at a loss. I would really appreciate an answer that would solve this issue. I just want the rsvp button to show users who havent rsvped for the specific post/event.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to me is a database constraint. You want to instruct the database to throw an error in those cases.

In a migration

```
add_index :rsvps, [:user_id, :post_id], unique: true
```

And a validation that reflect that, just to make rails aware of this

```
validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :post_id }
```

Now we're sure that no more than one pair some_user_id, some_post_id is present in the database.

Now, let's instruct the view to not display the button in those cases

```
<% unless Rsvp.exists?(post: @post, user: @post.user) %>
  <div class="rsvp">
    <%= button_to "Rsvp now", rsvps_post_path(@post), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'd move that exists query in the action and use just a boolean here, this is just demonstrative.